# Python import error: no module named

Tags: python, python-import

I am very new at Python. I have an existing example project that has the scripts `YYY` in path `XXX/YYY`, and a script `A.py` that call these one by one.

I only want to add a script `ZZZ.py` to the `YYY` scripts so that call after them.
I add this script in the same path (`XXX/ZZZ.py`) and try to import it in the `A.py` and call it.

But I got this error:

```
python import error no module named XXX/ZZZ.py
```

I wonder: What is the difference?  Why can Python import `XXX/YYY` py files but return this error for `ZZZ.py`?

Comment: what are the actual import lines that work and the one that does not

Comment: The typical import in file A.py is :
import XXX.YYY as Y    
Y.doSomething()
import XXX.ZZZ as Z
Z.doSomethingElse()
Python can run Y.doSomething() but fails to import XXX.ZZZ!!

Answer (score 2):

If your modules are structured like this:

```
/XXX

    __init__.py
    ZZZ.py
    /YYY

        __init__.py

        *more scripts here*
```

And if the directory containing `XXX` is in your PYTHONPATH, then

```
import XXX.ZZZ as Z
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import ZZZ, do import `XXX.YYY.ZZZ as Z`. This assumes that YYY is a directory, and also assumes you actually put that ZZZ.py inside of YYY.