# Python import error: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am trying to do a python script that it is divided in multiple files, so I can maintain it more easily instead of making a very-long single file script.

Here is the directory structure:

```
wmlxgettext.py
<pywmlx>
  |- __init__.py
  |- (some other .py files)
  |- <state>
       |- __init__.py
       |- state.py
       |- machine.py
       |- lua_idle.py
```

if I reach the main directory of my project (where the wmlxgettext.py script is stored) and if I try to "import pywmlx" I have an import error (Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'state')

Here is the complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/programmi/my/python/wmlxgettext/true/pywmlx/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pywmlx.state as statemachine
  File "/home/user/programmi/my/python/wmlxgettext/true/pywmlx/state/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pywmlx.state.machine import setup
  File "/home/user/programmi/my/python/wmlxgettext/true/pywmlx/state/machine.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pywmlx.state.lua_idle import setup_luastates
  File "/home/user/programmi/my/python/wmlxgettext/true/pywmlx/state/lua_idle.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pywmlx.state.machine as statemachine
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'state'
```

Since I am in the "project main directory" pywmlx should be on PYTHONPATH (infact I have no troubles when I tried to import pywmlx/something.py)

I'm not able to figure where is my error and how to solve this problem.

Here is the **pywmlx/__init__.py** source:

```
# all following imports works well:
from pywmlx.wmlerr import ansi_setEnabled
from pywmlx.wmlerr import wmlerr
from pywmlx.wmlerr import wmlwarn
from pywmlx.postring import PoCommentedString
from pywmlx.postring import WmlNodeSentence
from pywmlx.postring import WmlNode 

# this is the import that does not work:
import pywmlx.state as statemachine
```

Here is the **pywmlx/state/__init__.py** source:

```
from pywmlx.state.machine import setup
from pywmlx.state.machine import run
```

But I think that the real problem is somewhat hidden in the "imports" used by one (or all) python modules stored in pywmlx/state directory.

Here is the **pywmlx/state/machine.py** source:

```
# State is a "virtual" class
from pywmlx.state.state import State
from pywmlx.state.lua_idle import setup_luastates
import pywmlx.nodemanip as nodemanip

def addstate(self, name, value):
    # code is not important for this question
    pass

def setup():
    setup_luastates()

def run(self, *, filebuf, fileref, fileno, startstate, waitwml=True):
    # to do
    pass
```

Finally here is the **pywmlx/state/lua_idle.py** source:

```
import re
import pywmlx.state.machine as statemachine
# State is a "virtual" class
from pywmlx.state.state import State

# every state is a subclass of State
# all proprieties were defined originally on the base State class:
    # self.regex and self.iffail were "None"
    # the body of "run" function was only "pass"
class LuaIdleState (State):
    def __init__(self):
        self.regex = re.compile(r'--.*?\s*#textdomain\s+(\S+)', re.I)
        self.iffail = 'lua_checkpo'

    def run(xline, match):
        statemachine._currentdomain = match.group(1)
        xline = None
        return (xline, 'lua_idle')


def setup_luastates():
    statemachine.addstate('lua_idle', LuaIdleState)
```

Sorry if I posted so much code and so many files... but I fear that the files, in  directory, hides more than a single import problem, so I published them all, hoping that I could explain the problem avoiding confusion.

I think that I miss something about how import works in python, so I hope this question can be useful also to other programmers, becouse I think I am not the only one who found the official documentation very difficult to understand when explaining import.

---

Searches Done:

[Not Useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917958/python-import-mechanics): I am already explicitly using import x.y.z all times I need to import something

[Not Useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201898/python-import-error-no-module-named): Even if the question asks about import errors, it seems not useful for the same reason as (1)

[Not Useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721415/python-import-problem): As far as I know, **pywmlx** should be located into PYTHONPATH since "current working directory" on my tests is the directory that contains the main python script and **pywmlx** directory. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Can you try changing the problematic import to `from . import state as statemachine`?

Comment: have you tried with empty __init__ files first? If this works try to not use aliasing (import as) as this can lead to namespace conflicts. I think you are having circular imports with messed up namespace. Try to always use the full name (only write import ..., no from imports).

Comment: @Serbitar: I'd like to "vote" your comment, becouse your suggestion works very well. Replacing __import pywmlx.state.machine as statemachine__ with only __import pywmlx.state.machine__ on __pywmlx/state/lua_idle.py__ works very well (probably, aliasing pywmlx.state.machine as statemachine create a conflict with the aliasing used by __pywmlx/\_\_init\_\_.py__ where __pywmlx.state__ is aliased as __statemachine__ too. I don't know how to mark a positive vote on your comment :/ I'd like to do it

Comment: Thanks, just added an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Python does several things when importing packages:

- Create an object in `sys.modules` for the package, with the name as key: `'pywmlx'`, `'pywmlx.state'`, `'pywmlx.state.machine'`, etc.
- Run the bytecode loaded for that module; this may create more modules.
- Once a module is fully loaded and it is located inside another package, set the module as an attribute of the parent module object. Thus the `sys.modules['pywmlx.state']` module is set as the `state` attribute on the `sys.modules['pywmlx']` module object.

That last step hasn't taken place yet in your example, but the following line only works when it has been set:

```
import pywmlx.state.machine as statemachine
```

because this looks up both `state` and `machine` as attributes first. Use this syntax instead:

```
from pywmlx.state import machine as statemachine
```

Alternatively, just use

```
import pywmlx.state.machine
```

and replace `statemachine.` everywhere else with `pywmlx.state.machine.`. This works because all that is added to your namespace is a reference to the `sys.modules['pywmlx']` module object and the attribute references won't need to be resolved until you use that reference in the functions and methods.

Comment: Thank very much for your answer. I'm not sure I understood all your explaination, but I appreciated the great job you did when you tried to explain such complex thing (understanding deeply how import works) in a simplified way. I didn't try your solution (wich probably will work well) since removing alias from the __import__ used on __lua_idle.py__ works as well and it is a solution that fits better what I'm trying to manage with namespaces used by pywmlx :)

Comment: @Nobun: sure, that works too; I've added that alternative to the answer.

Comment: `That last step hasn't taken place yet in your example` why is that do you think?

Comment: The import of `pywmlx.state` hasn't competed yet. During the execution of the module too-level code more imports are triggered (visible in the traceback) leading to an import that would only work if the `pywmlx.state` import had fully completed.

Answer (score 4):

You are having a circular import in your framework. Circular imports do not work well with aliases. When importing a module with an alias and then, during the circular import, importing it again without an alias, python complains. The solution is to not use aliases (the "import module as" syntax) but always use the full "import module" statement.

Comment: I think that this might be the correct answer. However, I am hoping that there is another way to get around it. It's just an alias so I was hoping that Python would be smart enough to replacing all instances of `pywmlx.state.machine` with `statemachine`.